# Can I get the filelocation of a file input to upload, or is there a better method?

Tags: node.js, file, input, upload, localserver

in my nodejs localserver code I can upload a predefined file to a service, and looks a little something like

```
    app.post("/postmedia", (request, response) =>{ 
    //...
        uploadMedia("file name", "c:/location/filelocation.mp4");
    //...
    }
```

Now, I'm trying to make it so you can select a file in my webapp, the selected file gets passed/POSTed to the nodejs server method that then uploads it as seen above.

My question is is it possible to get the file location of a selected file on your PC, or is that the wrong method/unsafe? Do I need to pass or upload the file to the nodejs server, then upload it with the method and delete it from there?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take your approach:

You have to upload it to your node server 1st. So on server you can create `temp` directory for that purpose and write cron to upload it to where ever you want.
After uploading the file you should delete it from node server so it doesn't grow bigger and bigger.

Other approach could be have a client side SDK(e.g `aws-sdk`) and upload it to your destination directly. So you don't need to manage uploading and deleting by your self.